# Calling method from Master.cs on any aspx page using javascript on Master.Master

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, master-pages

I want to offer a user discount (pop up) after 30 seconds being on site (any page). Since this project implements WebForms master page, I put the timer inside Master.aspx, and the method that communicates with db inside Master.cs. The method checks eligibility through calling stored procedure, and returns bool.

I set javascript timer inside aspx Master page, so after the time out, I want to call the method providing it userID. How can I call this isUserEligibleForDiscount method that's inside Master.cs using javascript?

```
setTimeout(function () {
            if (sessionStorage.getItem('timer') == 'on') {
                if (isUserEligibleForDiscount(userID)) { 
                    $('#myModal').modal('show');
                }
                sessionStorage.setItem('timer', 'off');
            }
        }, 30000);
```

Comment: Research `Page Methods`. Part of ASP.NET AJAX. Lots of info and Q&A online and here.

Comment: PageMethods are not available inside Master page

Comment: Not sure if I knew that before. Sry bout that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `[WebMethod]` attribute. It makes the method callable from remote Web clients [(WebMethodAttribute Class)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.services.webmethodattribute?view=netframework-4.8). 
Decorate your `isUserEligibleForDiscount` with that attribute.

You can then call the method via Ajax. You specify your page in the URL for the Ajax call: `'yourpage.aspx/isUserEligibleForDiscount'`

Answer (score 0):

You can put your method(s) into a page that does nothing but hold code, or you could call an asmx web service.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    doAjaxPageMethodCall();

    //if (sessionStorage.getItem('timer') == 'on') {
    //    if (isUserEligibleForDiscount(userID)) {
    //        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    //    }
    //    sessionStorage.setItem('timer', 'off');
    //}
}, 3000);

function doAjaxPageMethodCall() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",            
        // page-methods.aspx holds your methods. 
        // replace AjaxPageMethodCall w/ isUserEligibleForDiscount.
        url: "/page-methods.aspx/AjaxPageMethodCall", 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",            
        dataType: "json"
    }).done(function(data) {
        if(data.d===true) { 
            // show modal .
        }
    }).fail(function() {
        $("#lbl").html("Houston...");
    });
}
```

Of course you can combine the 2 functions, they're just split up for testing.

---

Web service is similar:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    <Services>
        <asp:ServiceReference Path="/web-services/test-service.asmx" />
    </Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

And the only change to the ajax call is the url:

```
url: "/web-services/test-service.asmx/HelloWorld", ...
```

Your test-service.cs file will hold the actual methods.